# Draw tick border around group of cells (TableLayoutPanel C#)

Tags: c#, border, tablelayout, cells, sudoku

I'm making a sudoku field in a windows form application (c#)

I've used a TableLayout to make my boxes to put labels in for the numbers displayed in the sudoku, now I need a thick border around every group of 3x3 cells (like a sudoku)...

I'm trying with the CellPaint object but I can't set a border around a group of borders...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1

- Create a UserControl
- Set Background to Black, Margin to 0, 0, 0, 0 and Padding to 3, 3, 3, 3
- Add a TableLayoutControl with 3 Row & 3 Cells (33% each)
- Set TableLayoutControl Dock to Fill and BackColor to Black
- Add a Label to each cell, Margin 1, BackColor White

Step 2

- Create another UserControl with 3x3 cells (33% each)
- add an instance of your first UserControl to every single cell
- now you have double borders where two controls are besides each other but you can easily adjust this by setting the padding for the indiviual usercontrols. I would suggest you leave the one in the middle with 3, 3, 3, 3 and modify the outer controls

Here is a sample, left is UserControl1, right is UserControl2 with 9x UserControl1
I used padding 4 on the outer sides and padding 2 on the inner sides.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Thx for feedback but we had to change the system of making the labels like you can see:

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an panel to the left top cell and set RowSpan and ColSpan of it to 3. After it you can draw any border on it.

Answer (score 0):

we had to change our code for making the labels and are doing it this way...

```
    const int spacing = 30;  //ruimte tussen kotjes
                    int aantal = (int)nudColsPerBlock.Value * (int)nudRowsPerBlock.Value; //totaal aantal kotjes per rij/kolom
                    Label[][] SudokuRaster = new Label[aantal][];
                    for (int x = 0; x
```

But I still need thick borders between some of the labels, any tips?